# How to show that $\lambda(D)=\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

I have a bit trouble showing that $\lambda(D)=\infty$.
I have been giving the following problem:
Given $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0<x=y<1\}$ and $\mathcal{N}=\{N \in \mathcal{B} | m_I(N)=0\}$ (where $m_I$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ restricted on the interval $(0,1)$) - and the measure $\lambda:\mathcal{B}\otimes \mathcal{B} \to [0,\infty]$, where
$$\lambda(G)=
    \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{ if }\, \exists N_1,N_2 \in \mathcal{N}, B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B}, \text{ then } G \subseteq (B_1 \times N_1) \cup (N_2 \times B_2)  \\
        \infty & \text{ or else }\\
    \end{cases}
$$
Show that $\lambda(D)=\infty$.
I get that I might have to show it by contradiction, but I have only gotten so far:
Assume by contradiction, that $\lambda(D)\neq \infty \Longrightarrow \lambda(D)=0$, then $\exists N_1, N_2 \in \mathcal{N}$ and $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, where $D\subseteq (B_1 \times N_1) \cup (N_2 \times B_2)$.
For $D\subseteq (N_2\times B_2)$, I have that for $N_2\in \mathcal{N}$ it applies that $m_I(N_2)=0$.

Can somebody give me a hint, on how to get moving? I assume that for $D \subseteq (B_1 \times N_1)$, it follows analogously. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $D \subseteq (B_1 \times N_1) \cup (N_2 \times B_2)$. We want to find a contradiction.

Note that you can write the elements of $D$ in this way
$$D= \{ (t,t) : t \in (0,1) \}$$

Define $$I_1 = \{ t \in (0,1) : (t,t) \in (B_1 \times N_1) \}$$
and analogously
$$I_2 = \{ t \in (0,1) : (t,t) \in (N_2 \times B_2) \}$$
By our assumption you have that $(0,1) \subseteq I_1 \cup I_2$.

On the other hand, if you look carefully at the definition of $I_1$ and $I_2$ you can see that
$$I_1 \subseteq N_1 \qquad I_2 \subseteq N_2$$
To show this, let $t \in I_1$. Then $(t,t) \in B_1 \times N_1$. This means that $t \in B_1$ and $t \in N_1$. In particular this implies $t \in N_1$. By arbitrarity of $t \in I_1$, we have $I_1 \subseteq N_1$ (actually we can say more: $I_1 = B_1 \cap N_1$). The proof of $I_2 \subseteq N_2$ is similar.

Hence
$$(0,1) \subseteq N_1 \cup N_2$$
This contradicts monotonicity of the Lebesgue measure, since $N_1 \cup N_2$ has measure zero.

Comment: Oh, I have noticed, that I have forgotten to write, that $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, not $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}$, in the definition of D. Does this change anything? Also, I noticed that you write that $t$ is in the closed interval $[0,1]$, but the Lebesgue measure is restricted on the open interval $(0,1)$. Why can you say that? Is it because of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I misread the question. It should be the open interval $(0,1)$ not $[0,1]$. But this makes no difference. I hope my argument is clear.

Comment: It is very clear. I think I understand the approach better now.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I do not think I understand the argument for  $I_1 \subseteq N_1$ and $I_2 \subseteq N_2$ ?

Comment: @compaq.43 I modified my answer with an explanation. I thought it was obvious, this is the reason why I didn't write it. Maybe the confusion arises from the fact that $(0,1)$ denotes the interval, while $(t,t)$ denotes the couple of two coordinates?